# How can I get number of occurrences of an array element and save element with counter like python dictionary in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

```php
$cartItemsArray = ["", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "2", "3"];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($cartItemsArray); $i++) {
   echo $cartItemsArray[$i] . "<br />";
}
```

Here `$cartItemsArray` is an array of some id's. I want to count the occurences of every element and save it in an array.

`I want output like below:`

```php
Array = [1:"1", 2:"2", 3:"3", 4:"1"];
```

I want to save these array.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array like this.

```
$cartItemsArray = ["", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "2", "3"];

$return = [];

foreach ($cartItemsArray as $card) {
    if (!isset($return[$card])) {
        $return[$card] = 0;
    }
    
    $return[$card]++;
}
```

Comment: but, i think the comment below your question is better than my answer

Comment: OK... bro... that solution may be more efficient. <3 Thanks agains bro.... but your  logic makes me think of the algo.

Comment: Bro.. One more question. When I try to find a value of an element how to do that in php?.